# Kids' science fiction, 60s or early 70s, moon worms

Tags: story-identification, books, astronauts, toys

This was an illustrated children's science-fiction book I read in the early 1970s, but had a very 1960s feel (thinking back now). There were a couple of astronauts on the moon. Somehow they got into a system of strange, round tunnels. The tunnels turned out to be made by giant worms.

I don't remember anything else about the plot, but I associate the book with some astronaut figure toys I had at the same time - I'm fairly sure the toy astronauts were a tie-in to the book. The figures were about 5-6" tall, in bright orange and white spacesuits, and made of rubber over a wire skeleton, so they were very poseable. They had plastic space helmets.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That figure sounds like Matt Mason and this [link](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17889898-major-matt-mason-moon-mission---a-big-little-book) confirms there was a tie-in book with moon worms:

> The writing is iffy at best but wildly, and I mean WILDLY imaginative:
> moon rabbits, moon worms, "nothing" beings--and all the great Major
> Matt Mason vehicles.

[image]

It appears to have been a Whitman Big Little Book, and is listed on a collector's info [page](http://www.biglittlebooks.com/listings/Whitman-2000-1967-1969.htm) like this:

> MW28  2022        MAJOR MATT MASON - MOON MISSION         4   8   16
>
> Big Little Book 2000 Series®; 1968. Hard cover. Size: 3 7/8" x 5' x 7/8";
>
> 4-color illustrations; 256 pages. Author: George S. Elrick. Artist: Unknown.
>
> COLLECTOR'S NOTE: No price printed on cover.

A text file of the entire book is available at the Internet Archive [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20111112075627/http://www.majormattmason.net/blb.htm).

I had Matt and some of his accessories back in the day, but sadly I didn't have this book.  Matt's spacesuit was white, but his colleague Sergeant Storm had an orange suit.

[image]

That internal "wire skeleton" broke if you played with them too much :(

Comment: That's it, thanks helping me remember a piece of my childhood. :-)

Comment: Matt Mason - the MM explains why I had "Mike Mars" stuck in my head, but that's a different set of semi-fictional books dealing with NASA.

Comment: I'm sorry I missed reading it back in the day....it's available from resellers, but pricey.

Comment: I think I recall eventually breaking off one of my guys' arms.  Also the orange/white paint on the black rubber tended to peel after a while.

Comment: We had his weird alien friend Captain Lazer too - he was made of hard plastic.

Comment: Apparently there were several other characters, aliens, and accessories- but I only had Matt and Sgt Storm, and the book.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_Matt_Mason